# How to check for repeating characters in a string and numer their position

Tags: java, arrays, string

What I need is the code to convert a string like "acaAAb" in "a13cA45b", because "a" is the first and third letter in the string and "A" is in the fourth and fifth.

I'm pretty new to java and I have no idea what to do. My code so far is:

```
String resSplit[] = res.split("");
String str;
for(int i = 0; i < resSplit.length; i++){
    str = resSplit[i];
    for (int j = -1; (j = res.indexOf(str, j + 1)) != -1; ){
        resSplit[i] = resSplit[i] + (j+1);
    }
}
for(int i = 0; i < resSplit.length; i++){
    for(int j = 1; j < resSplit.length; j++){
        if(resSplit[i].equals(resSplit[j])){
    //      resSplit[i] = "";
        }
    }
}
res = "";
for(int i = 0; i < resSplit.length; i++){
    res = res + resSplit[i];
}
```

Where res is the string to convert, and if res is for example "acAAb" the output is "a1c2A34A34b5".

Please help!

Examples:
"Accb" to "Ac23b"
"cCbb" to "cCb34"
"bAca" stays the same because there are not more than one of each letter

EDIT:
I want to give numbers only to the letters that appear more than once

EDIT:
Please don't "-1" my question because you don't understand it. I'm not english, I'm doing my best to explain it! You'll get me blocked :\

Comment: So you want to ignore c and b in the string?

Comment: Could You explain input and output of conversion ?

Comment: I want to give numers to the letters that appear more than once, and leave the others "numberless"

Comment: so  "acaAAb" in "ac13A45b" ?

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what i need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
for (int j = -1; (j = res.indexOf(str, j + 1)) != -1; ){
    resSplit[i] = resSplit[i] + (j+1);
}
```

You can check if `(j+1)` is greater than 0. If yes, then only add the number.

eg:

```
for (int j = -1; (j = res.indexOf(str, j + 1)) != -1; ){
    resSplit[i] = resSplit[i] + ( (j+1)>0 ? j+1 : "" );
}
```

Comment: resSplit[i] + ( (j+1)>0) gives me an error: Cannot convert from string to boolean

Comment: It didn't change, if i give it "acAAb" it still converts it into  "a1c2A34A34b5" instead of acA34b :c

Comment: Well at least you taught me about the "? :" stuff, thanks c: